# Amazon Web Services - cronjob not running every minute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I have a cronjob defined on an AWS ec2 (so it uses crontab). I did `crontab -e` and added this line into it:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/file/file.php
```

I saved it with vim and it says `crontab: installing new crontab`. I also made the permissions on the file `755`, using chmod, and I put the proper shebang (`#!/usr/bin/php -q`) at the top of `file.php`. The script should update a database every minute, but I am not seeing the database get updated at all. What did I do wrong?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking if the script runs at all? e.g. instead of checking the db, have the file change something else, e.g. create a temp file,s end an email, etc... to confirm that it's executing. if that happens, then start digging into the script and debug at what stage it's blowing up. and since you're doing `/usr/bin/php scritp`, the 755 permissions and #! shebang are redundant. a php script executed by this method only needs to grant read permissions.

Comment: @MarcB thanks for the advice, Ill try to drill down and see

Comment: @heinst Further to Marc's comment, I would recommend you output to a log file such as a timestamp (this also verifies if the script is running every minute0 and writing other potentially useful run-time script information (i.e. did connect to DB, prior to making a DB change, after making a DB change,etc.) so that you can see if the script is doing what you think it is doing. Is it possible to post at least part of the PHP script minus any user credentials. For example, just make username = user and password = pass if you include part of the code here.

Comment: Repeat pattern like /2 for every 2 minutes or /10 for every 10 minutes is not supported by all operating systems. Worse, some operating system will accept the time specification but will refuse to run. Use `*` instead. It already means every minute.

Answer (score 1):

logging example:
*/1 * * * *   >> /var/log//your_cron.log 2>&1